# Code placement in php

Tags: php

[image: I'm trying to get $adminbutton and $admibutton2 on the same row]

At the moment my table duplicates the teams which I dont want it to do. I had moved the $adminbutton2 to the desired colume on the table

```
<table style ="background: #5b9bc6;
margin: auto;"
>
<tr>
<th>rank</th>
<th>team</th>
<th>win count</th>
<?php IF(isadmin())
{
    echo ("<th>Add wins</th>");
    echo ("<th>Revert wins</th>");
} ?>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="SELECT `id`, `teamname`, `wincount`,`AdminU` FROM `teamranks` ORDER BY 
`wincount` DESC";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
$rank = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $adminbutton ="";
    $teamid= $row['id'];
    if (isadmin()){
        $adminbutton="<button onclick=\"addwin($teamid)\" 
type=\"button\">Add win</button>";
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$rank."</td><td>". $row['teamname']."</td><td 
id=\"wincount-$teamid\">".$row ['wincount'] . "</td><td>$adminbutton</td>
<td></td></tr>";
    $rank++;
}
?>
<?php
$sql="SELECT `id`, `teamname`, `wincount` FROM `teamranks` ORDER BY 
 `wincount` DESC";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
$rank = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $adminbutton2 ="";
    $teamid= $row['id'];
    if (isadmin()){
        $adminbutton2="<button onclick=\"revertwin($teamid)\" 
type=\"button\">revert win</button>";
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$rank."</td><td>". $row['teamname']."</td><td 
id=\"wincount-$teamid\">".$row ['wincount'] . "</td><td></td>
<td>$adminbutton2</td><td></td>/tr>";
    $rank++;
}
?>

</table>
```

It basically duplicates the teams and there ranks as well as their win count. All the code present works but it does not display where I want it to. I know I probably have a lot of unnecessary code in there but if you someone could help me figure out what to keep and place in the right place and what to remove that would be great!

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the Stack Overflow question rather than just a screen shot.

Comment: Hi, I'm incredible sorry about that. I tried to do that And it wasn't liking my formatting at all. Is there an easy way of getting it formatted correctly from notepad++ to here.

Comment: [Read how to correctly format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). There is a special button for such things on your question textarea box.

Comment: Even with the code, I still can't make sense of what's being asked here.

Comment: After pasting your code. Select it and click the code sample button in the textarea

Comment: Also [read the Stack Overflow help area](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: There are multiple separate issues with your code. I would suggest reading up on a recommended high quality PHP coursebook.

Comment: I cant work out what you are trying to do? You seem to have essentially 2 identical loops?

Comment: Oh i see, you just need 2 buttons per row (add and delete) if admin

Comment: Yea, that was so I can see if i can get $adminbutton2 working which it does. I just want it in a table form with 1 list of teams and $adminbutton and $adminbutton2 right next to each other

Comment: Oh by the way don't worry about the AdminU I called in the first table that's for something future at the moment it does not need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $adminbutton= "";
    $adminbutton2= "";
    $teamid = $row['id'];
    if(isadmin()){
        $adminbutton = "<button onclick=\"addwin($teamid)\" type=\"button\">Add win</button>";
        $adminbutton2 = "<button onclick=\"revertwin($teamid)\" type=\"button\">Revert win</button>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>".$rank."</td><td>".$row['teamname']."</td><td id=\"wincount-$teamid\">".$row['wincount'] . "<td><td>$adminbutton</td><td>$adminbutton2</td><td></td></tr>";
    $rank++;
}
```

Like @Martin suggested, your code has some issues and you'll need to read up or practice more. There are some awesome tutorials on Youtube, Udemy and other sites.

From what I can understand from your screenshot, it looks like you want two buttons with in each row $adminbutton and $adminbutton2. Looks like you duplicated the Query and changed the button.

**SOLUTION**

- Replace your code Line **77 - 84** with the above code
- Delete the code Line **85 - 99**

Comment: Thank you so much! the line numbers were a off by one or two. But once I fixed that my code Worked!